# Building help in rails appi

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering, is there solution for building help in my rails application, in a form of gem.

I searched net, but no matter how question is formed, what I got is only help about basic learning ror.

Comment: Hi Stanko, it's not clear what you are asking. Could you edit your question to be more specific? Including some code would be a great start

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @stanko-brus, I would recommend you to read this [guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question in order to help users to understand your problem.

Comment: How to create a ruby gem? is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I can be more specific. There are a lot of gems for rails. Devise for user registration for example. I wonder, is there gem that I can use for creating "online" help for my rails app? Help that I can make that user can use during using my rails app.